# MERN APP - how do I access express params with id in my react component using context api

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongoose, mern

hi im trying to access specific user data from the api on the front end but everytime i make a request with the id param i am getting undefined, when testing using postman the api works, im creating the app with react.js, express, node.js and mongoose.

```js
index.js
app.use("/login/account", transactionsRouter);

route
router.get("/usertransactions/:id", auth, getUserTransactions);

controller
const userTransactions = await Transaction.findById(req.params.id)

testing with postman 
GET /login/account/usertransactions/613f36721808da26a8434e44 200 90.698 ms - 177

react.js
  let { id } = useParams();
  async function getUserTransactions(amount) {
    const config = {
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
    };
    try {
      const result = await API.get(
        `/login/account/usertransactions/${id}`,
        config,
        amount
      );

      dispatch({
        type: "GET_TRANSACTIONS",
        payload: result.data.data,
      });
    } catch (error) {
      dispatch({
        type: "TRANSACTIONS_ERROR",
        payload: error.id,
      });
    }
}
```

Comment: I am confused by the expression result.data.data, could you log result and check the object structure ?

Comment: hi when i console log the result.data.data i get an object with all users and there tranactions, thats when i delete the id                                                                               console.log("res: /login/account/usertransactions/{i have removed the id}", result.data.data);                            res: /login/account/usertransactions/ 
(4) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0:
amount: 10
createdAt: "2021-09-13T11:30:55.036Z"
userId: "612c08060a6f019a6023ffe5"
__v: 0
_id: "613f366f1808da26a8434e42"